# How to add a margin to the boxStroke inside TextInputLayout [ XML Material Design ]

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-design, material-components-android

How to add a margin to the boxStroke inside TextInputLayout to keep the stroke from going out while using "boxCornerRadiusBottom".

```
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        style="@style/Widget.Material3.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Test"
                        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="16dp"
                        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="16dp"
                        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="16dp"
                        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="16dp"
                        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/_03_add">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Result:
[Image of Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfvPH.png)

What i want:
[Image of Wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfReB.png)

I´m using Material 3 inside an Android project

---

Thanks for any answer :)

I have tried to set app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp" what hides the box.
[I would like to keep it but with a margin]